# Standard format for writing Compressed Row Storage into text files?

Tags: c, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse matrix stored in Compressed Row Storage (CRS) format. This is basically three arrays: an array containing the Values, an array for Column Index, and a final array containing the Row Pointers. E.g. http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~dongarra/etemplates/node373.html

I want to write this information into a text (.txt) file, which is intended to be read and put into three arrays using **C**. I currently plan to do this by writing all the entries in the Value array in one long line separated by commas. E.g. 5.6,10,456,78.2,... etc. Then do the same for the other two arrays.

My **C** code will end read the first line, put all the values into an array labeled "Value". And so on.

**Question**

Is this "correct"? Or is there a standard way of putting CRS data into text files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No standard format that I'm aware of.  You decide on a format that makes your life easy.

First, consider that if you want to look at one of these text files, you'll be instantly put off by the long lines.  Some text editors might simply hate you.  There's nothing wrong with splitting lines up.

Second, consider writing out the number of elements in each array (well, I suppose there's only two different array lengths for the three arrays) at the beginning of the file.  This will let you preallocate your arrays.  If you have all array lengths at hand, you have the option of doing a single memory allocation.

Finally, consider writing out some sensible tag names.  Some kind of header that can identify your file is the correct format, then something to denote the start of each array.  It's kind of a sanity thing for your code to detect problems with the file.  It might just be one character, but it's something.

Now... call me a grungy old programmer, but I'd probably just write whole lot in binary.  Especially if it's floating point data, I wouldn't want to deal with the loss of precision you get when you write out numbers as text (or the space they can consume when you write them with full precision).  Binary files are easy to write and quick to run.  You just have to be careful if you're going to be using them across platforms with different endian order.

That's my 2 cents worth..  Hope it's useful to you.

Comment: The idea in your third paragraph (about storing the length of each line) will prevent you from modifying the text file by hand easily. This is something I'd consider premature optimization. Binary format is usually a huge no-no since it often turns out **very** handy to be able to read or tweak the text file by hand. (words of wisdom [there](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch05s01.html)). I agree with everything else in your advice.

Comment: It probably depends on the author's intent.  Since they didn't give one, I gave some suggestions to consider.  Now, regarding array sizes, adding a value to the matrix by hand is way harder than the issue of tweaking one or two numbers at the top of the file.  Unless you change the last row, you have to adjust all the row pointers that follow the row you inserted at.  Screw that! =)

Comment: True. Tweaking CSR by hand is probably not worth it after all, and storing the row length does indeed make sense in this respect. If the intent is to modify the files (and not just be able to read them to check everything is ok) it's probably better to just store (row, column, value) triples, one by line.

Comment: In general it would make the most versatile sparse matrix file format, I agree...  but writing triples is not that helpful in reading the file back into the CRS format.  I would maybe write the row on a single line, followed by pairs of (column, value) on the following lines.  Maybe even terminate that with an empty line for clarity.

Comment: Yes, "You decide on a format that makes your life easy" is the most important part here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and for the useful discussion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to some widely-used standards, have a look at the [Matrix Market](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/). This is a repository with many matrices arising in a variety of engineering and science problems. You can find software libraries to save and read the matrices as well.